# How can I set an arbitary Host header in Python 3 urllib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

For example, I would like to send a request to `12.34.56.78` with host header `stackoverflow.com`. However, Python seems to overwrite the Host header, and the actual packet sent still has `Host: 12.34.56.78`.

How can I stop this behavior?

```
from urllib import request
a = request.build_opener()
a.addheaders.append(('Host', 'stackoverflow.com'))
a.open('http://12.34.56.78/')
```

Note: the code runs on Python 3

Comment: Maybe create a `Request` instead with the headers you need and then do `urlopen(request)`?

Answer (score 4):

Thanks [Blurp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8651755/blurp) for his idea, a way to send the request is:

```
from urllib import request
r = request.Request('http://12.34.56.78/', headers={'Host': 'stackoverflow.com'})
request.urlopen(r)
```